# Ionic capacitor gives Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT error

Tags: angular, http, ionic-framework, capacitor

I am new to ionic and i tried to run my application on my device via the `ionic capacitor run android -l  --external`  command.At first i got a `net::ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED` after adding `<application  android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">` into the AndroidManifest.xml file the error disapeared but now i get a `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT` error.I also tried to disable my antiviurs/firewall but it did nothing.

I tried to make a post request with http (angular),I used for the post call the ip adress.If i run the application on the browser it works.How can I revole this error?

Comment: Do you need to have your IP whitelisted to access the api endpoint? Maybe you're using a data connection on your device, instead of a whitelisted wi-fi for your browser serve.